# undefined method `Ques_id' for #<Questionnaires:0x007fcc490c88f8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application Questionnaires its my controller in that one datatype is t.integer "Ques_id" its not able to acess in my index page.when i run the index page then i will get NoMethodError in Questionnaires#index  error. How to solve this error?

## table

```
class CreateQuestionnaires< ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :questionnaires do |t|
      #t.column "id", :string, :limit => 25
      t.integer "Ques_id"
      t.string "Qname"
      t.string "Header"
      t.string "Description"
      t.string "username"


    end
  end
   def down
     drop_table :questionnaires
   end
end
```

### controller

```
class QuestionnairesController < ApplicationController
 # layout false
  layout "admin"
    def index
    @questionnaires = Questionnaires.sorted()
    end

  def view
    @questionnaires= Questionnaires.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @questionnaires= Questionnaires.new()
  end

  def create
    # Instantiate a new object using form parameters
    @questionnaires = Questionnaires.new(questionnaires_params)
    # Save the object
    if @questionnaires.save
      # If save succeeds, redirect to the index action
      flash[:notice] = "questions saved successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def edit
    @questionnaires = Questionnaires.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    # Find an existing object using form parameters
    @questionnaires= Questionnaires.find(params[:id])
    # Update the object
    if @Questionnaires.update_attributes(questionnaires_params)
      # If update succeeds, redirect to the index action
      flash[:notice] = "questions updated successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'view', :id => @questionnaires.id)
    else
      # If update fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('edit')
    end
  end

  def delete
    @Questionnaires= Questionnaires.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    questionnaires = Questionnaires.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "questions '#{Questionnaires.name}' destroyed successfully."
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end


  private

    def questionnaires_params
      # same as using "params[:subject]", except that it:
      # - raises an error if :subject is not present
      # - allows listed attributes to be mass-assigned
      params.require(:questionnaires).permit(:Ques_id,:Qname, :Header, :Description, :visible)
    end

end
```

### index page here i got error

```
<% @page_title = "Questionnaires" %>

<div class="Questionnaires index"
  <h2>Questionnaires </h2>

  <%= link_to("Add New questions", {:action => 'new'}, :class => 'action new') %><br>
 <div><%= pluralize(@questionnaires.size, 'questionnaires') %> found</div>
  <th>Questionnaires</th>
  <table class="listing" summary="Questionnaires list">
    <tr class="Header">
      <th>Ques_id</th>
      <th>Qname</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <% @questionnaires.each do |objQuestionaire| %>
    <tr class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

      <td><%= objQuestionaire.Ques_id %></td>
      <td><%= objQuestionaire.Qname %></td>
      <td><%= objQuestionaire.Header %></td>
      <td><%= objQuestionaire.Description %></td>
      <!--td><%= objQuestionaire.username %></td-->


      <td class="actions">
        <%= link_to("view", {:action => 'view', :id => objQuestionaire.id}, :class => 'action view') %>
       <!-- <%= link_to("view", '#', :class => 'action view') %>-->
      <!--  <%= link_to("Edit", '#', :class => 'action edit') %>-->
         <%= link_to("edit", {:action => 'view', :id => objQuestionaire.id}, :class => 'action edit') %>

      </td>
      <%end %>

##its my error page
 Showing /home/cabox/workspace/app_1/app/views/questionnaires/index.html.erb where line #20 raised:

undefined method `Ques_id' for #<Questionnaires:0x007fcc490c88f8>

Extracted source (around line #20):

17
18
19
20
21
22
23




       <% @questionnaires.each do |objQuestionaire| %>
       <tr class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

         <td><%= objQuestionaire.Ques_id %></td>
         <td><%= objQuestionaire.Qname %></td>
         <td><%= objQuestionaire.Header %></td>
         <td><%= objQuestionaire.Description %></td>

Rails.root: /home/cabox/workspace/app_1
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/questionnaires/index.html.erb:20:in `block in _app_views_questionnaires_index_html_erb__3549852765576469128_70257686505360'
app/views/questionnaires/index.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_questionnaires_index_html_erb__3549852765576469128_70257686505360'
```

Comment: try this in your console: `Questionnaires.column_names`, what do you get?

Comment: .1.2 :001 > Questionnaires.column_names                                                                                      
 => ["id", "Qname", "Header", "Description", "username"]                                                                      
2.1.2 id column is default .but i want one more column Ques_id with interger  datatype

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate` after adding the column?

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for a Ques_id column in your table(Questionnaires) which is not been migrated yet. So only it throws

```
 `NoMethodError`
```

Please update your database by doing

```
rake db:migrate
```

which will migrate all the required fields defined in the migration file to your database so that it will not throw error.

Comment: Try accessing your record via rails console and do
`Questionnaire.new` and check whether ques_id field is available or not in your database table